# JavaScript: How to better indicate (highlight) current nav page during scroll than just using "scrollY > x"

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I currently have a simple webpage layout that is divided in 4 sections (HOME / ABOUT / SKILLS / CONTACT).

Here is my JS code that highlights a specific section from the Nav-bar when a certain pixel amount has been reached during scroll:

```
let home = document.querySelector(".btn1")
let about = document.querySelector(".btn2")
let skills = document.querySelector(".btn3")
let contact = document.querySelector(".btn4")

function highlight(){
  if(window.scrollY > 1)
  {
    home.classList.add("highlight")
  }

  if(window.scrollY > 550)
  {
    home.classList.remove("highlight")
    about.classList.add("highlight")
  }
  else{
    about.classList.remove("highlight")
  }

  if(window.scrollY > 1210)
  {
    skills.classList.add("highlight")
    about.classList.remove("highlight")
  }
  else{
    skills.classList.remove("highlight")
  }

  if(window.scrollY > 2050)
  {
    contact.classList.add("highlight")
    skills.classList.remove("highlight")
  }
  else{
    contact.classList.remove("highlight")
  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", highlight);
```

This works fine on my 24" monitor, but gets inaccurate if viewport height gets bigger, such as on a 27" monitor.

What better way can I target each page section with scroll?

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code. Code is text. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please edit your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for that, made it into text instead.

Comment: Investigate IntersectionObserver - that will alert you when each section comes into the viewport (or similar) and so is device-dimension independent. Let me know if you need more help with that.

Answer (score 1):

Make a script where you define the elements that you need to reach in order for the state to update (with the use of `.offsetTop`)

Now the pixels value will dynamically change as the viewport changes.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle explaining your idea? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I ended up comparing `scrollY` with each page's  `.offsetTop` and it did the trick!

Although now if I resize my browser, the function in JS will work but its assuming the viewport size of original window even though its been resized, it only catches on that its been resized if I refresh page! Any pro tips ?